# A USB-A hub or Thunderbolt 2 hub with USB-C ports in it?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, thunderbolt

I have only USB-A and Thunderbolt 2 ports on my Macbook Pro. Is there a product out there that is a USB-A hub (or a Thunderbolt 2 hub) that includes USB-C ports within it?

If not, how can I plug in devices that require USB-C when my Macbook Pro only has USB-A and Thunderbolt 2 ports?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add USB-C ports to an old 2014 iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389416/add-usb-c-ports-to-an-old-2014-imac) I know I posted an answer, but the more I think about your question, the more I think your question is a duplicate of the linked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize your question refers to a USB Type-A hub, where as below I refer to cables and adaptors. However, the same issues, with respect to the cables and adaptors, would also occur with hubs.

Actually, cables and adaptors with a USB Type-A plug and USB Type-C receptacle are not defined or allowed by the [USB Type-C® Cable and Connector Specification Revision 2.1](https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-revision-21). This is stated in the last paragraph of Section 2.2, which is repeated below.

> USB Type-C receptacle to USB legacy adapters are explicitly not defined or allowed. Such adapters would allow many invalid and potentially unsafe cable connections to be constructed by users.

However despite this fact, there of plenty of such cables and adaptors which can be inexpensively purchased. For example, see this the question [Add USB-C ports to an old 2014 iMac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/389416/add-usb-c-ports-to-an-old-2014-imac). I should point out that this type of solution would limit the maximum data transfer rate to 5 Gb/s.

The safer route would be get a Thunderbolt 3 dock and connect to the Mac through the [Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) to Thunderbolt 2 Adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter). For example OWC offers this [Thunderbolt 3 Dock](https://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/TB3DK14PSG/). I should point out that this type of solution is significantly more expensive.

Comment: An excellent answer, I say so because I would have written a nearly verbatim answer myself.  One addition I'll make though is that OWC will soon release a new Thunderbolt dock and hub that should provide more USB-C ports and still work by using the Thunderbolt 2 to Thunderbolt 3 adapter.  Dock: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-dock And hub: https://eshop.macsales.com/shop/owc-thunderbolt-hub  I have no affiliation with OWC beyond being a happy customer.